# How to install zeromq4-haskell on windows? (can't find zmq dependency )

Tags: windows, haskell, zeromq

I installed zmq from the windows binaries http://zeromq.org/distro:microsoft-windows then ran:

```
cabal install zeromq4-haskell --extra-include-dirs="F:\thirdparty\ZeroMQ4.0.4\include\" --extra-lib-dirs="F:\thirdparty\ZeroMQ4.0.4\lib\"
```

But I'm still missing the zmq dependency:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring zeromq4-haskell-0.6.4...
Failed to install zeromq4-haskell-0.6.4
Build log ( C:\Users\calin\AppData\Roaming\cabal\logs\zeromq4-haskell-0.6.4.log ):
Configuring zeromq4-haskell-0.6.4...
setup-Simple-Cabal-1.22.5.0-x86_64-windows-ghc-7.10.3.exe: Missing dependency
on a foreign library:
* Missing C library: zmq
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
--extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
zeromq4-haskell-0.6.4 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I also tried following this page, but I couldn't get anywhere http://gettingsharper.de/2015/06/23/bridging-the-worlds-with-omq/ . I didn't get what he meant by /bin or /lib.

```
cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.22.6.0
using version 1.22.5.0 of the Cabal library

ghci --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.10.3
```

I need this to install ihaskell. Help?

Answer (score 5):

It seems like I managed to solve it:

1. copy `<ZMQ>\lib\libzmq-v120-mt-4_0_4.lib` to `<ZMQ>\lib\zmq.lib`
2. copy `<ZMQ>\bin\libzmq-v120-mt-4_0_4.dll` to `System32\zmq.dll`
3. run:

```bash
cabal install zeromq4-haskell --extra-include-dirs=<ZMQ>\include --extra-lib-dirs=<ZMQ>\lib
```